# How to sync a second controller to an Xbox One for splitscreen Minecraft

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I sync a second controller to my Xbox One to play 2 player Minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

From [Xbox Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/connect-a-wireless-controller):

> 1. Turn on your Xbox One.
> 2. Insert AA batteries (or rechargeable batteries
>    from the Xbox One Play & Charge Kit) into the controller. See Using AA
>    batteries in your Xbox One Wireless Controller.
> 3. Turn on your
>    controller by pressing and holding the Xbox button. (The Xbox button
>    is located in the middle of the controller near the top.) The Xbox
>    button  will flash. When the button stays lit, the controller is
>    connected.  Note If the controller doesn't turn on, check the
>    batteries. If you're using rechargeable batteries, make sure they're
>    charged.
> 4. Press and release the connect button on the Xbox.
> 5. Within 20 seconds, press and hold the controller’s connect button (a circular button on top of the controller as you hold it in your hands) until the controller's Xbox button flashes a few times. That means it's searching for a console. The Xbox button stays lit once it's connected.

Depending on what model console you have, the location of the connect button in step 4 is different.  For the Xbox One X and S, it is under the power button on the Xbox.  For the original Xbox One, it is on the left side of the console if you are looking at it head on.

Xbox One X location (virtually the same spot for the Xbox One S as well):

[image: Xbox One X]

Original Xbox One location:

[image: Original Xbox One]

After that, when playing Minecraft, make a game that is **not** an online world (uncheck the Online game option when making the world).  Once the world loads up, press start on the second controller to sign in a second person to play splitscreen.  Check the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen) for additional information.